# Table padding using the MS Word COM object in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, com

I've got some code here that will create a basic table in a Word document using PHP, it creates the table and populates it just fine, but I really need to shunt the table across so that the address (first box of the table) fits into a windowed envelope!

```
    $word->ActiveDocument->Tables->Add ( $word->Selection->Range, 1, 3 ); //creates table with 3 columns

    $word->Selection->TypeText ( $pretext [0] );
    $word->Selection->MoveRight (); //move to next column
    $word->Selection->TypeText ( $pretext [1] );
    $word->Selection->MoveRight (); //move to next column
    $word->Selection->TypeText ( $pretext [2] );
    $word->Selection->MoveRight (); //move off the table
```

Any suggestions would be fantastic - it seems really difficult to find any decent documentation for this online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are RightPadding, TopPadding and so on.

You find the Reference at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212430%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
(choose the used version, the link points to Word2003 )

Comment: Thank you so much! Just need to try and work out how to convert that into the PHP code now, but hopefully won't be *too* hard :o